# spotify playlistsForUserWithSession call returns invalid array

Tags: ios, spotify

When calling playlistsForUserWithSession on the latest beta iOS sdk for spotify, i get back what appears to be a proper array, as i can do a 'po pl.items' and it shows a list of playlists in the debug window. However, if i try to do a pl.items.count i get "member reference base type 'void *' is not a structure or union" and if i try pl.items[0] returns error "subscript of pointer to incomplete type 'void'" Here's my code. Thanks:

```
SPTAuth *auth = [SPTAuth defaultInstance];

//get list of current playlists
[SPTPlaylistList playlistsForUserWithSession:auth.session callback:^(NSError *error, id object) {

    if (!error) {
        NSURL *playlistURL = nil;
        pl= object;

       //at this point, the pl object isn't playing nice
        if(pl != nil && pl.items != nil && pl.items.count > 0) {
            playlistURL = [pl.items[0] uri];
        } else {
           //snipped code
        }
        NSString * theResult = [playlistURL absoluteString];
        //snipped code
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Problem with the Spotify media Picker...");
        }
    }
}];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it turns out that the objects were working ok if i access them via code, but they did not work if i tried to look at them with the PO command, so it appears all is well.

Answer (score 0):

In my implementation, I use `tracksForPlayback` method delegate from `SPTTrackProvider`

A code snippet

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) SPTPlaylistList *SpotifyLists;

SPTPartialPlaylist *partialPlayList = [[_SpotifyLists tracksForPlayback] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
UIImage *placeHolder = [UIImage imageNamed:@"PlaceHolder.jpg"];
[cell.profileImageView setImageWithURL:partialPlayList.smallestImage.imageURL placeholderImage:placeHolder];
cell.titleLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", partialPlayList.name];
cell.auxilaryLabel.text = [@(partialPlayList.trackCount) stringValue];
```

Not quite sure when to use the `items` property though

Comment: Yes, but how do you populate the list? How do you know the list of playlists that belong to a given user? It looks like you are providing a specific list from your tableView, but how are you populating the tableview to begin with?

Comment: Use the same method as you are using `[SPTPlaylistList playlistsForUserWithSession:session callback:^(NSError *error, SPTPlaylistList *lists) {}];`

Comment: yes, and when i use it, i get back the improper array. That's the problem.

Comment: Well, I think you should open an issue about this. `items` and `tracksForPlayback` are confusing and can't distinguish when to use which one. Sorry that I can't help about this.